# python hard-coded multi-char delimiter vs passed multi-char delimiter

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script which is using csv DictReader to read a csv with unicode delimiter '\x1f'.

I am running the script by calling a bash shell script which is passing the delimiter as follows:

```
python python_script.py '\x1f' import.csv
```

however, I am getting following error:
**TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string**

but when I hard-code the delimiter into the python script like this:

`reader = csv.DictReader(import.csv, delimiter='\x1f')` it works, while

`reader = csv.DictReader(import.csv, delimiter=sys.argv[1])` gives above 1-character string error mentioned above.

How can I pass the multi-byte delimiter from shell script above without hard-coding the delimiter in the python script?

Comment: We would need a simple example of how you use that parameter, but likely you need to call `ast.literal_eval` on the parameter. The python compiler converts `'\x1f` to a single character - but the compiler doesn't run against the command arguments.

Comment: You are confusing shell strings with Python string *literals*.

Comment: @tdelaney can you please clarify? I have edited the question with example code on which I am getting the error.

Comment: @rici has a good solution - use the shell's literal string evaluator to get the character you want. Alternately, you could use python's `ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])` - except I realized that doesn't quite work without a bit of fiddling - something like `ast.literal_eval('"' + sys.argv[1] + '"')` so that the character sequence is compiled by python.

Comment: @tdelaney: Instead of `literal_eval`, which can be touchy if there are quotes in the string, you could use something like `codecs.decode(sys.argv[1], 'unicode_escape')`. Of course, you'd still need to do appropriate error checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bash:

```bash
python python_script.py $'\x1f' import.csv
```

Shells don't interpret escape sequences, including `\x..`, so you need to use bash's [ANSI-C escaping syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Other shells have similar mechanisms, but there's not a lot of consistency. You can use `"$(printf '\37')"` on any Posix shell.